# Phalcon - Syntax error, unexpected token AS, near to ' a, UNSIGNED ) AS intHours

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

On MySql Workbench sql works fine.

```
SELECT id, hours, 
CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(hours, '%H'), SIGNED) AS intHours, 
CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(hours, '%i'), SIGNED) AS intMinutes 
FROM jobdone_work_hours
```

Phalcon ( 1.3.4 ) show error

```
    $result = $mm->executeQuery(
        "SELECT id, hours, 
            CONVERT( DATE_FORMAT(hours, '%H'), UNSIGNED ) AS intHours, 
            CONVERT( DATE_FORMAT(hours, '%i'), UNSIGNED ) AS intMinutes 
            FROM SoilTechJobDone\Api\Models\JobdoneWorkHours 
            WHERE fk_staff_id = :staffEmpId: 
            AND confirmed='1' 
            AND date BETWEEN :dateStart: AND :dateEnd: 
            order by date",  
        [
            'staffEmpId' => $staffEmpId,
            'dateStart' => $dateStart,
            'dateEnd' => $dateEnd,
        ]
    );
```

**Phalcon error:**

```
Syntax error, unexpected token AS, near to ' a, UNSIGNED ) AS intHours, CONVERT( DATE ...
```

**What he does not like.**

Comment: Something funny's going on with the `%H`... it looks like that's being interpolated before the query's run.

Answer (score 0):

Phalcon PHQL is not 1:1 MySQL. Mor likely DATE_FORMAT or CONVERT is not known by phalcon. Phalcon 1.3.4 is not supported like years, so i can't really help you with this, in phlcon 3 there is option to add extensions to dialect it's recognized by PHQL(similar stuff like in DQL).